# How to graph values versus time axis?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I'd like to use Excel 2010 to show on the x-axis when discrete events occurred and on the y-axis the magnitude of those individual spurious events. My goal is to try to visually analyse when different magnitude events occur and to see if there is a periodicity to these events.

How to go about this using Excel graphs?

Answer (score 1):

Use a (Y X) Scatter plot. With this chart the values on the time axis don't have to be regular.

- Select the data to plot
- Click Insert tab
- Click Scatter
- Select the chart type